# Django : How to access a localhost database hosted by a user?

Tags: django, database, python-3.x

I want to develop a website (with it's own database) where all the users will host a tiny database on their computer (SQlite or mySQl). I need to find a way for the users to access their local database and work with it on the website.

I read the docs concerning the multi-database (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/) we can in the settings tell to django which database it needs to  connect to.

For example :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

How to tell django to connect to the database hosted by the user ? I assume that 127.0.0.1 will refer to localhost of the django server. Am i right ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstood the concepts behing Django, or backend at all.

Django runs on a host, it could be a server, cloud hosting, on your local machine, etc.. When you use 127.0.0.1 as the database server host address, you are targeting localhost of the host where Django is running. You cannot simply start a MySQL server on the client side from django or python, you cannot do anything. You cannot even start a SQLite database as the django simply has no ability to see to user's filesystem.

What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you want to build something on top of a local database, it has to run locally, or you will have to somehow mount the database files to the django, which will be a snapshot instead of realtime change relfection.

Comment: Hi, The aim is not to start a MySQL server on the client side. After registration on the website the client will download and install a database (for example MySQL). My question is how to communicate between my django server and their local database without addind all the IP of the client database. I don't know if it's more understandable like this.